# Add info to Celery's get_task_logger

Tags: logging, celery

The recommended way to log in Celery is to use these two lines

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
```

and then in the task itselt do `logger.info(...)`

However, I would like to add more details; in my case the name of the `user`.
***All*** my tasks have it as the first parameter of the task.

Is there (a simple) way to enhance the behavior of the logger?
Currently I simply do something like:

```
logger.info('[{}] My log message is {}'.format(user, 42))
```

but this quite an ugly solution (not to mention annoying to use)